# Ocelot Gateway Post requests Issue

Tags: .net, postman, swagger, ocelot

I am using ocelot as a gateway and the get requests are working perfectly
but the post requests returns 400 bad request

[Bad Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOqSb.png)

but this same request is working on postman and returning 200 as the image says

[Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMp5M.png)

we can notice that both swagger and postman are pointing to the same url so the problem is not with ocelot.json file. howerver, this is my Ocelot.json File

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 44340
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/v1/starter/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete" ],
      "SwaggerKey": "starter"
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 21021
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/v1/abpstarter/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete" ],
      "SwaggerKey": "abpstarter"
    }
  ],
  "SwaggerEndPoints": [
    {
      "Key": "starter",
      "Config": [
        {
          "Name": "starter API",
          "Version": "v1",  
          "Url": "https://localhost:44340/swagger/v1/swagger.json"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "abpstarter",
      "Config": [
        {
          "Name": "abpstarter API",
          "Version": "v1",
          "Url": "http://localhost:21021/swagger/v1/swagger.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:3000",
    "RequestIdKey": "OcRequestId"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 400 error you're facing when making requests via Swagger can have several possible causes. As the requests work correctly in Postman, the issue might be related to the Ocelot configuration or how Swagger is interacting with it. Keep in mind that the difference in behavior between Postman and Swagger might be due to various reasons including headers, authentication, CORS, and other application-specific settings. Could you share with us the swagger configuration for the ocelot? I would suggest you to recheck the swagger configuration.

Comment: builder.Services.AddSwaggerForOcelot(builder.Configuration);

app.UseSwaggerForOcelotUI(opt =>
{
        opt.PathToSwaggerGenerator = "/swagger/docs";
});

Comment: Have you tried to add this property to your routes? "DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator": true, must be added for each route

Answer (score 0):

it worked fine when I Commented this "AddControllersWithViews" in the startup file in the Downstream Services because it Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks